# Check if a string has a word in it greater than 15 characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I want to make a conditional statement that will check if:

```
comment.user.name
```

(which may return something like `"Montgomery Philips Ridiculouslylonglastname"`) contains any words with greater than 15 characters.

Something like:

```
if comment.user.name.split(" ").???
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
comment.user.name.split.any? { |x| x.length > 20 }
```

Here is the wonderful [`enumerable`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) mixin documentation for it.

Comment: Should it just be `split` instead of `split('.')`?

Comment: @Mischa Well, I thought his original string had `.` on it to split on.  I could be wrong.

Comment: Quote from question: (which may return something like "Montgomery Philips Ridiculouslylonglastname")

Comment: create a whole new array just to check if a string contains long words isn't the best IMHO :-)

Comment: @ProGNOMmers I'm afraid of regular expressions!  Not really.  Just a fan of that mixin.

Answer (score 5):

Just FYI (as you have already found an appropriate answer), doing it with a regex:

```
/\b[a-z]{15,}\b/i
```

If you find a match, there's a word longer than 15 characters (20 in the title).

Answer (score 2):

Using regexps is cleaner than creating a whole new array just to check if a string matches some pattern (regexps were made for this!):

```
('a'*19+' '+'a'*19) =~ /[^ ]{20}/ #=> nil
('a'*19+' '+'a'*20) =~ /[^ ]{20}/ #=> 20
```

This is what I mean:

```sh
$ ruby -rbenchmark -e 'long_string = ([("a"*20)]*1000).join(" ")
puts Benchmark.measure{ 100.times{ long_string.split.any? { |x| x.length > 20 } }  }'
#=>   0.050000   0.000000   0.050000 (  0.051955)
```

```sh
$ ruby -rbenchmark -e 'long_string = ([("a"*20)]*1000).join(" ")
puts Benchmark.measure{ 100.times{ long_string  =~ /[^ ]{20}/ }  }'
#=>   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000128)
```

And the regexp version is ~ 365 times faster than the `string.split.any?` one!

Comment: `\S` is not quite it I think. There's a difference between a non-space char and a word char.

Comment: @pguardiario you're right; the matching pattern closest to `split(' ')` probably is `[^ ]` (which is also faster than `\S`) (answer updated)

Answer (score 0):

```
w = "Montgomery Philips Ridiculouslylonglastname" 
w.split().any? {|i| i[16] != nil} #=> true

"Montgomery Philips".split().any? {|i| i[16] != nil} #=> false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def contains_longer_than length
  comment.user.name.split.select{|x| x.length > length}.size > 0
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Loamhoof is close but there's a much simpler regex:

```
/\w{16}/
```